Is is a problem to fractionate a plant extract containing plastic?
I made a huge mistake when preparing a leaf extract. I had Frozen leaves and I try to crush on a blender before putting the solvent. It was a little hard to crush and I put a little bit of solvent (dichloromethane) but it was a plastic blender and the solvent obviously reacted with the plastic a little. I feel dumb but I cannot repeat so I just procceded, made paper filtration and then put on rotavapor. The extract presents a plastic aspect even after filtration and rotavaporation. Is it worth to proceed the fractionations and isolation of my target compound? Thanks a lot.

What is the target compound ( the class/categorization could be enough)? Describe the  procedure you were going to follow if the DCM accident would not have happened. (Add the elaboration to the question text.)

It is a triterpenoid. I would ressuspender the dry extract in DCM, weight the dry extract after removal of the solvent and start fractionation

I have hoped for more polar compounds. If there is available preparative gel exclusion chromatography for medium/low polar mobile phase, I would try it, if the sample it worthy. But with DCM - I doubt...

Or possibly vacuum distillation, if applicable. But the question is if it is worthy the trouble.
